Unable to determine why my Excel Sheet is bloated
Have a source workbook that contains ERP data. I'm taking that data and copying to another workbook ('Results' tab) which contains my macro's for processing.
Unless this is expected, the dataset is 17k row X 21 columns and the Workbook is 1.7mb which seems very large. I've tried all the tricks in the book reduce the size, but to no avail.  Most importantly, I have confirmed excel is recognizing the last cell where I would expect, Row 17k X column 21.
I have tried the following :

delete the unused rows/columns
change row height and column width
I do have named ranges on the "Results" tab but when they are removed, it does not decrease the file size
I've delete all other tabs to confirm the 'Results' IS the culprit

One thing that did work slightly was copying results tab to a BRAND NEW workbook, which reduced the size by about .5 mb. Why would that work?
Unless that ~1.7mb is expected with a dataset of my size, I just can't see that being the case.
Any other suggestions?

Your CSV experience suggests your xlsx file is not bloated; Shared Strings probably explain why your xlsx is smaller than the CSV (and there are probably a lot of repeated 'phrases' in an ERP download). You might consider saving your file as an xlsb to achieve a smaller file size.

You’ve got a file with 17,000 rows × 21 columns, and it’s 1.7 MB. For that amount of data, the size feels excessive unless there’s something hidden or unnecessary inflating it. Let’s figure out what’s causing the bloat and fix it.
Step 1: Clear Out Extra Formatting
Excel is notorious for holding onto formatting in cells you aren’t even using. This can silently add to the file size.
Here’s What You Do:
Select the entire worksheet by pressing Ctrl + A.
Go to the ribbon at the top and click Home > Clear > Clear Formats.
Save, close the file, and reopen it to see if the size has shrunk.
Why this works: Sometimes, even blank cells beyond your data range have formatting (like bold, colors, etc.), and Excel saves all of that information unnecessarily.
Step 2: Check What Excel Thinks is the Last Cell
Sometimes Excel “remembers” rows and columns beyond where your actual data ends.
Try This:
Press Ctrl + End. This will take you to the cell Excel thinks is the end of your data.
If this is way beyond your actual data, delete those rows and columns:
Highlight extra rows (e.g., 17,001 onwards), right-click, and choose Delete.
Do the same for columns beyond your data.
Save and reopen the file. This resets Excel’s memory.
Why this works: Deleting rows/columns doesn’t always clean up Excel’s internal “used range.” Saving and reopening forces Excel to recalculate.
Step 3: Hidden Objects or Shapes
Sometimes invisible objects—like charts, images, or shapes—can bloat your file.
Check for This:
Go to Home > Find & Select > Selection Pane.
This will show you all objects on the sheet, even hidden ones.
Delete anything unnecessary.
Why this works: Hidden elements, even if not visible, still take up space in the file.
Step 4: Look at Conditional Formatting
Conditional formatting rules can pile up, especially if they apply to large ranges of cells.
Clean It Up:
Go to Home > Conditional Formatting > Manage Rules.
Check all rules for the sheet and delete anything unnecessary.
Why this works: Even if the rules aren’t obvious, Excel still processes them and saves them, increasing file size.
Step 5: Check for Named Ranges
Named ranges are useful, but old or unused ones can hang around and add unnecessary bulk.
Here’s How:
Go to Formulas > Name Manager.
Review the list of named ranges. Delete anything you don’t need.
Why this works: Named ranges that reference large areas or don’t serve a purpose anymore can bloat your file.
Step 6: Start Fresh
This might feel like a cheat, but copying everything into a new workbook often solves the issue.
Here’s the Process:
Open a new blank workbook.
Copy your data from the bloated workbook (only the necessary tabs).
Paste into the new file. Ideally, use Paste Special > Values to remove extra formatting.
Save the new workbook and check its size.
Why this works: Excel leaves behind a lot of “junk” in the original file—metadata, unused styles, and hidden content. Starting fresh strips all that out.
Step 7: Save in a Clean Format
Certain Excel file formats are heavier than others. If your file is .xls or .xlsm, it’ll likely be larger.
What to Do:
Save your file as .xlsx (unless you need macros).
If you’re just testing, save the file as .csv (this removes all formatting) and see if the size reduces.
Why this works: .xlsx is a modern format that handles data more efficiently than older Excel formats.
Why Copying to a New Workbook Helped Earlier
When you copied your “Results” tab to a fresh workbook, Excel stripped out all the unnecessary baggage (like unused styles, hidden formatting, or corruption). This is why the file became smaller. It’s a good quick-fix solution!
Expected File Size
For your dataset, a clean file should ideally be 200 KB to 500 KB, depending on how much formatting or extra content you need. If it’s still over 1 MB after all this, something unusual is still lurking.

Thank you for all those tips!!  So interestingly enough, taking my tab in question (Results), and saving as csv, it actually doubled in size.  Why?
Copying the data to a NEW workbook worked slightly as I mentioned in my first post.  I tried all of your other tips with no success. Something must be whacky...
